# Ejecutar If sin recargar pagina HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Esta es la parte del `script` que tengo en mi `html`, el primer `setInterval` me actualiza los datos de la pagina externa sin problema, pero tengo una duda con la etiqueta `"#PDiferencia"`.

Lo que quiero hacer es cambiar el color del texto sin recargar la pagina.

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(actualizar, 1000);
  setInterval(actualizar1, 600);
});

function actualizar() {
  $("#PDiferencia").load('Tags.html div#PDiferencia');
  $("#PFalla").load('Tags.html div#PFalla');
}

function actualizar1() {
  CDiferencia = document.getElementById("PDiferencia").value;
  if (CDiferencia >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("PActual").style.color = "lime";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("PActual").style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

Comment: Tiene la duda con #PDiferencia pero su codigo refiere a PActual.  Es lo que intentó?

Comment: Hola,  así es, según el valor de #PDiferencia  debe cambiar el color del párrafo PActual, Creo que al ejecutar el .load no me actualiza #PDiferencia con numero

Answer (score 0):

Te respondo en base a lo que pude investigar con tu codigo, copié el codigo y los intervalos

```
setInterval(actualizar, 1000);//este se ejecuta segundo
setInterval(actualizar1, 600);//este se ejecuta primero
```

La funcion actualizar1, suponiendo que los datos no los obtiene del primer actualizar, el IF del actualizar1 no va a obtener ningun valor. Recomiendo que primero en los setInterval los ubiques de la siguiente manera aproximadamente

```
setInterval(actualizar, 600);//ahora este se ejecuta primero
setInterval(actualizar1, 1000);//este se ejecuta segundo
```

De esta manera puede actualizar los datos para luego cambiar el color segun el valor obtenido. Este puede ser una manera.

Otro problema que puede ser, es que quieras obtener un valor de un HTML y no de un campo de texto, es decir:

```
CDiferencia = document.getElementById("PDiferencia").value;//obtiene el valor de un campo de texto
```

si queremos obtener el valor de una etiqueta div y no de un formulario se deberia poner (teniendo en cuenta tu codigo):

```
CDiferencia = document.getElementById("PDiferencia").innerHTML;//obtiene TODO valor de la etiqueta con id
//hay que asegurarse que dentro de la etiqueta no haya otra cosa que no sea un numero
```

En caso de que quieras obtener un valor de un campo de texto deberias poner el ID de ese campo input y no el ID del Div.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar o a orientarte a la solucion de tu problema. Cualquier duda edito la respuesta.